# Issue with running Restsharp SpecFlow tests using MSTest via command line

Tags: automated-testing, test-design, specflow, testing-strategies

I have created `restsharp specflow tests` using `NUnit` framework and I am using `MSTest` as a `test runner` in `app.config` file. I tried to run the tests via command line and it does not work - says the tests are not found.

These are the commands I have tried:

1. `bin\Debug\MSTest /testcontainer:[prjectfilename.dll] /test[specflow feature file name]`
2. `bin\Debug\MSTest /testcontainer:[prjectfilename.dll] /test[specflow scenario name]`
3. `bin\Debug\MSTest /testcontainer:[prjectfilename.dll] /category[specflow tag name]`
4. `bin\Debug\MSTest /testcontainer:[full path for prjectfilename.dll /test:[specflow feature file name]`

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5157466/6793637

Comment: Both are different frameworks , why you want to mix it up

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/ms182487(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Runner

Comment: Try using nunit console.exe instead of mstest